# Making my activities private in my profile in Trello

Tags: trello

I love Trello, but would like my activities to be private on my profile. It doesn't make much sense to have a private organization or board if the activities you contribute to that board or organization are not private.

Is there a way to make the activities section of my profile private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public should not be able to see your activity on a private board. If you have an example of this, please submit it to support@trello.com.

It might be that the item is private but that's not obvious to you. We're working to make the visibility of a particular item more obvious.